# Wifi device not found

Tags: networking

I installed Ubuntu on an HP WiFi-only PC. After Installation The OS does not find the WiFi device. This is my maiden voyage with Ubuntu. I suspect that I did something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Is this a desktop computer, or a laptop? Either way, please give the make/model of the computer as well as the make/model of the wireless adapter/wireless card if known. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1176452/edit) your question with the output of `ip link show`, and `netstat -i`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You may not have done anything wrong, some brand devices are easy, many cheaper ones are not. Following the docs can be helpful, ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  (if you get stuck, when you get to *device recognition and operation*, you'll gain details about your chipsets found in your device which are the key clues to fixing your issue, and us helping you).

Comment: Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: d4c6e6@X15:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
 Kernel modules: bcma

d4c6e6@X15:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Thank you @guiverc

Comment: Thank you  @chili555

Comment: Thank you  @Pilot6

Answer (score 0):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS, connect to the Internet using your phone and run in a terminal

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

That will install the driver.

Comment: d4c6e6@X15:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for d4c6e6: 
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving &apos;security.ubuntu.com&apos;
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving &apos;us.archive.ubuntu.com&apos;
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving &apos;us.archive.ubuntu.com&apos;

Comment: Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving &apos;us.archive.ubuntu.com&apos;
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving &apos;us.archive.ubuntu.com&apos;
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving &apos;us.archive.ubuntu.com&apos;

Comment: : Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving &apos;us.archive.ubuntu.com&apos;
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving &apos;security.ubuntu.com&apos;
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving &apos;security.ubuntu.com&apos;
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used insteadd4c6e6@X15:~$ sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: You didn't connect to the Internet. The answer said to connect to the Internet using your phone. You just ran the command. If you don't have a phone, you can use an offline method form the duplicate link.

Comment: i have a phone that was connected to the web. I used a usb cable to connect the phone to the laptop.